# How to disabled Ctrl+P and Ctrl+S? in ng2-pdfjs-viewer. Right now anyone can print or download using keys.Any suggestion would be appreciated would

Tags: javascript, angular7

I am using ng2-pdfjs-viewer library to display pdf in my angular 7 app. Problem is if print flag is false button to print is not visible that works as expected but user can right click or use CTRL+P or CTRL+S and print or download the pdf. I want to restrict user to use those keys. I tried using JavaScript methods in my dom but those are not working as PDFJS component is overlapping.After all i tried to modify viewer.js file under node_modules folder that worked for me in my machine but we are using Jenkins build tool which use files from SVN and i can not commit node_modules to SVN. Jenkins use libraries from server on the base of package.json so my modification is use less in this case.I tried onBeforePrint event as well that is not invoked don't know why. Please help me on this how we can do that alternatively. Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

writing down the code i tried to modify the viewer.js

Code in my component

```py
<mat-dialog-content class="my-2 d-flex justify-content-center px-2">
  <div class="w-100 h-100">
    <ng2-pdfjs-viewer [download]="isPrintable" (onBeforePrint)="beforePrint()" [print]="isPrintable" *ngIf="pdfContent" [pdfSrc]="pdfContent"></ng2-pdfjs-viewer>
</div> 
</mat-dialog-content>
```

viewer.js modifications

```py
//To disable right click print added by KK on 29/08/2019
window.oncontextmenu = function () {
return false;
}
var hasAttachEvent = !!document.attachEvent;
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {

  //code to prevent download and print using CTRL+S and CTRL+P added by KK on 29/08/2019
  if ((event.keyCode === 80 || event.keyCode === 83) && (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) && !event.altKey && (!event.shiftKey || window.chrome || window.opera)) {
    //window.print();

    if (hasAttachEvent) {
      return;
    }

    event.preventDefault();

    if (event.stopImmediatePropagation) {
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    } else {
      event.stopPropagation();
    }

    return;
  }

}, false);
```

```py
 // CTRL + P key combinations you want to disable
  @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 80) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: if your goal is to stop a user from downloading a PDF, you can't. Since the browser has downloaded the PDF, it is available to the user to do with as they please

Comment: If you don't want people to download or print your material, don't put it online. The best you can do is set the actual permissions on the PDF itself, but even those are trivially circumvented so there's really no point: if you don't want people to download or print your data, don't offer it to them in a downloadable, printable fashion. And good luck, because even if nothing else, there's always screenshots.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But i have to give user pdf online because it's a book so user can see and download also if user has permissions. If we can find a way to prevent CTRL+S,CTRL+P and right click then user can't print or download i think.

Answer (score -1):

Worked for me (jQuery used):

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  // on Ctrl+S
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.which == 83) {
    return false
  }
})
```